# How many six digit numbers start with the same two digits and end with the same three digits?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations, big-list

Say that there is a 6 digit number 
the first digit is not allowed to be 0 or 1

so

How many number combinations start with the same two digits and end with the same three digits

ie.119333, 448222, 889888 etc..

My thoughts are 8_ 1_ 10_ 10_ 1_ 1_ = 8*10*10=800?

and how would I do it if instead of the and it said Or?

first of all, I'm I on the correct path here?
any other examples similar would help.

Comment: Your title should be specific to the problem at hand so that someone who has a similar question can find it if she or he searches the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your count is correct.

Now let us find the number of possibilities if our number starts with the same two digits **OR** ends with the same three digits. Again we assume that $0$ and $1$ are forbidden as first digit. But they may occur as second digit, for example in $506888$.

There are $(8)(10^4)$ numbers that begin with two equal digits, the first (and therefore second) digit being neither $0$ or $1$.

There are $(8)(10^3)$ numbers that start with an allowed digit and whose last three digits are the same.

If we add the two numbers above, we will have **double-counted** the numbers in which the first two digits are the same, and the last three are the same.

It follows that the required number is $(8)(10^4)+(8)(10^3)-(8)(10^2)$.

**Remark:** This is a relatively simple instance of a technique called **Inclusion/Exclusion.** There are more elaborate versions.

Comment: so Just minus the AND part?

Comment: Yes.  A general formula for two sets is $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$. Here $|X|$ means the number of elements in the set $X$.

Comment: how would one go about in determine the count if at least one digit appears more then once in the combination.. i.e 252169

Comment: This is a different problem, since we no longer have two identical digits at the beginning, or three at the end. I will assume that $0$ is forbidden at the beginning. Then if we had no further restrictions, the answer would be $(9)(10^5)$. Now we subtract the **bad** numbers, in which all digits are distinct. Let us count the bad numbers. I will stop here and continue in the next comment.

Comment: (Continued) For counting the bad numbers, there are $9$ choices for the first digit. For each of these there are $9$ choices for the second digit, since $0$ is now allowed. For each choice of first two digits, there are $8$ choices for third digit, and so on, for a total of $(9)(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)$.

Comment: why is it that it is  9*9*8*7*6*5? and not 987654?

Comment: You wanted to count the numbers in which some digit appears at least once. The analysis above says there are $(9)(10^5)-(9)(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)$. I suspect that in your comment above you are subtracting the bigger number from the smaller one.

Comment: oh I think I notice why now, thank you, you have been much help

Comment: About "why is it", I explained it in the comment. There are $9$ choices for first digit, since $0$ is forbidden as the first digit of a $6$-digit number. Imagine you have chosen $4$ as first digit. Then you cannot choose $4$ as the second digit, since we are producing numbers with all digits distinct. But you can choose $0$ as second digit. So for every legal choice of first digit, there are $9$ choices for second digit. And then $8$ choices for the third, and so on. The situation is different if we are making six-digit **strings**, initial $0$ not forbidden. Then it is $(10)(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)$.

Comment: You are welcome. One has to give full answers to someone with a name like learnmore.